# Is it possible to run only subsets of a Boost unit test module?

Tags: unit-testing, boost

I am using the Boost 1.34.1 unit test framework. (I know the version is ancient, but right now **updating or switching frameworks is not an option** for technical reasons.)

I have a single test module (`#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE UnitTests`) that consists of three test suites (`BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( Suite1 );`) which in turn consist of several `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE()`s.

**My question:**

Is it possible to run only a subset of the test module, i.e. limit the test run to only one test suite, or even only one test case?

*Reasoning:*

I integrated the unit tests into our automake framework, so that the whole module is run on `make check`. I wouldn't want to split it up into multiple modules, because our application generates lots of output and it is nice to see the test summary at the bottom ("X of Y tests failed") instead of spread across several thousand lines of output.

But a full test run is also time consuming, and the output of the test you're looking for is likewise drowned; thus, it would be nice if I could somehow limit the scope of the tests being run.

The Boost documentation left me pretty confused and none the wiser; anyone around who might have a suggestion? (Some trickery allowing to split up the test module while still receiving a usable test summary would also be welcome.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [--run_test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/run-by-name.html) parameter - it should provide what you're after.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if I use a test fixture. how do I specify a specific test in that case?

Comment: @ChristopherPisz: Does work for me. You have to give the name of the test, not the one of the fixture.