# boost unit test filter when using a fixture

Tags: c++, boost, boost-unit-test-framework

I need to specify a specific unit test to run. Of course, I looked at Stack Overflow Answers after I looked at the documentation, but neither used a fixture.

How do I specify a test case to run if I have:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(mysuite)

struct Fixture
{
    Fixture()
    {
        BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Setup");
    }

    ~Fixture()
    {
        BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Teardown");
    }
};

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(add_remove, Fixture)
{
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

If I pass `--run_test=add_remove`, the process returns with a message *Test setup error: no test cases matching filter or all test cases were disabled.*

I've looked at:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/runtime_config/test_unit_filtering.html

[Is it possible to run only subsets of a Boost unit test module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116789/is-it-possible-to-run-only-subsets-of-a-boost-unit-test-module)

[How to set which Boost unit test to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103886/how-to-set-which-boost-unit-test-to-run)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using the path to the test case as the argument to `--run_test`, it must also include the name of the suite. In your case, pass `--run_test=mysuite/add_remove`. This is described in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/runtime_config/test_unit_filtering.html#boost_test.runtime_config.test_unit_filtering.command_line_control) (look at the table in that section).

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab97699ee13f2719)